# Merge Ruby arrays and concatenate elements in it

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays

```
arr1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
arr2 = ["e","f","g","h"]
```

and I want to get a result like this

```
arr3 = ["ae","bf","cg","dh"]
```

How can I do that in ruby?

Comment: use this arr1.map.with_index { |e, i| e + arr2[i] } as it is faster and see same question here at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22312536/merging-only-respective-elements-of-two-arrays-in-one-array-in-ruby

Answer (score 2):

I'd do using [`#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) :

```
arr1 = ["a","b","c","d"] 
arr2 = ["e","f","g","h"]
arr1.zip(arr2).map(&:join)
# => ["ae", "bf", "cg", "dh"]
```

Comment: I did the same... but you are always faster! :)

Comment: The use of `zip/join` seems like the obvious solution.  Have no idea why it would be downvoted.